# Why does the elisp function not work (as I expect it to)?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I was wanting to write something that would move back one window in emacs, and bind to `C-x S-o`

```
(global-set-key [C-x S-o] '(other-window -1))
```

When I load a .emacs containg it, something breaks, all my scroll bars reappear (having previously been disabled), and `C-x S-O` functions exactly as `C-x o`.

A fix would be nice, but I'd also be grateful for an explanation of why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've messed up the key vector, and I believe you have to use a single function name, with no arguments, to make this work:

```
(global-set-key "\C-xO" 'my-other-window)

(defun my-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window -1)
  )
```

See the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html) for more details:

```
(info "(emacs)Init Rebinding")
```

Comment: For some reason, I assume that lisp had currying.

Comment: @MrBones This isn't about currying, this is about what Emacs requires for something to be bound to a key.  `interactive`

Answer (score 6):

You can't call functions with parameters directly like that in `global-set-key`.  It should be like this:

```
(global-set-key [C-x S-o] (lambda() (interactive) (other-window -1)))
```

which wraps the function you want in an anonymous interactive form.

Comment: If you want more info, see [Commands for Binding Keys](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html) and [Key Lookup](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Lookup.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual; the latter page tells you what kinds of things you can give as an argument to `global-set-key`.

Comment: If you use the key vector, it should be [?\C-x ?\O] I think.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. It does the same thing that mine does. However, I changed the key description to "\C-xO", from Tyler's answer, and it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems with your code:

1. You need [interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html#Interactive-Call) in the form which you're binding to a key (it's also worth reading the [wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractiveFunction))
2. It's a good idea to use `kbd` to read in the key binding you want, 
   e.g. `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x O") '...)`